# Determine the location of a Windows taskbar button or thumbbar button?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

I have added some ThumbBar buttons via `ITaskbarList3`.  Now when those are clicked I'd like to open the action / dialog next to the taskbar button.   How can I find the screen coordinates of the taskbar button?

Thanks.

Comment: ...does this work on Windows 11 as-is?

Comment: It's supposed to be supported by Win11 .. testing in Win10 .. but Would like the method to find the taskbar button so I know where it was clicked (you can tell it's from those buttons via the THBN_CLICKED high word of the click).  I could use the cursor but still want to know the button location...

Comment: There is no *public* API to locate the positions of buttons on the Taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIAutomation. Find your way to the bottom of the tree and retrieve `UIA_BoundingRectanglePropertyId` for each child element.

Powershells ShortcutGuide does this, you can look at their code if you need additional help...